# Prevent GET access to some URI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a builtin feature in Codeigniter to know the HTTP Method aka request method (get / post / put...) in a controller ?
I think something like :

```
if ( ! $this->input->is_post() ) show_error('Access forbidden', 403 );
```

I want to forbid access to GET Method in functions requiring post inputs. I can't find something in the doc about this simple thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    exit();
}
//continue with your code. it's a POST.
```

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances you can use like the following

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
//abort
```

or you can create a CI helper for this.

> if you want to prevent post then use the string 'POST' in if condition. It is this straight
>   forward.

Under suspicious circumstances if you want to prevent post(if you feel that request method can be manipulated)

NOTE: i haven't used the following and it is just my instant idea.
check for http raw input data.

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

may be you can check for strlen greater than zero...
or add your logic here.

*Assuming that you are not looking to solve this only using codeigniter*.

Comment: a little overlooking made me do typos cause of the not operator in your if condition which made me think you were preventing post. anyway i did update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this one :

```
if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
    show_error('Access forbidden', 403 );
}
```